# How can I solve an 404 not found error with POST request using Insomnia and WordPress API?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, wordpress-rest-api, insomnia

I'm using WordPress API and testing my routes with Insomnia software.

Everything works good with my GET routes but not with my POST routes.

I have 2 POST routes: one to register and one to log in.
I also use JWT token.

Here is my POST route to log in :

```
http://localhost/Barbieshop/jwt-auth/v1/token
```

[image: Setting login route]

```
Auth : no authentication
```

I get an `404 Not Found` answer

Here is my Register route :
`http://localhost/Barbieshop/wp-json/wp/v2/users/register`
[image: Setting for Register route]

Here is my .htacess file information :

```
>RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wp/
>RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
>#Plugin JWT auth
>RewriteEngine on
>RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
>RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the port, for example, http://localhost:5000/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Hugo, not necessarily, just localhost refers to the default 80 port